# jQuery dynamic object selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at the following code:

```
        this.forms = {
            signIn: {
                email: $('#tb-input-sign-in-email'),
                password: $('#tb-input-sign-in-password')
            },
            signUp: {
                fullName: $('#tb-input-sign-up-full-name'),
                email: $('#tb-input-sign-up-email'),
                password: $('#tb-input-sign-up-password')
            }
        };
```

This is my old code that initializes my textbox jQuery plugin:

```
$('#tb-sign-in-email, #tb-sign-in-password').textbox();
```

The new code (using the this.forms array) would be:

```
this.forms.signIn.email.textbox();
this.forms.signIn.password.textbox();
```

Basically I want to initialize the textbox plugin with one line of code just as the "old code" initializes the jQuery plugin (with a single selector).

Comment: so why is the "old code" not working anymore?

Comment: Really can't get what you are trying to achieve. For me both variants do the job.

Comment: Or is it just that your ids have changed from `#tb-sign-in-email` to `#tb-input-sign-in-email` and this is why the "old code" selector isn't working anymore?

Comment: It is working both ways, that is not the question, I updated my question (last line). Sorry if the question was not clear enough the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method

```
var textbox = this.forms.signIn ;

 (textbox.email).add(textbox.password).textbox();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code only get the elements on DOM using a jQuery selector, the same happens on the old code.

The difference is that the new code changes the selectors.
**From** `#tb-sign-in-email` **to** `#tb-input-sign-in-email`.
**From** `#tb-sign-in-password` **to** `#tb-input-sign-in-password`.

`$('#tb-input-sign-in-email, #tb-input-sign-in-password').textbox();`